# Stripe STPAddCardViewController navigation bar not showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, stripe-payments

I am using stripe in my code. I have one `navigationBar` in my `viewController`.

Here is the image of my `viewController`:

[image]

But when I navigate to `STPAddCardViewController`, navigation bar of `STPAddCardViewController` isn't shown. I am using this code:

```
let addCardViewController = STPAddCardViewController()

addCardViewController.delegate = self

navigationController?.pushViewController(addCardViewController, animated: true)
```

Here is the resulting image:

[image]

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you, possibly somewhere else in your code, doing something of the sort (or similar) that would result in hiding the nav bar ?

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true`

With just the snippet you posted it's I think hard to say exactly why this is happening. We might need to see a bit more code of your ViewController

I would suggest looking to see if your code is not doing something like the above.

Here is a very bare bone example VC that uses `AddCardViewController` pushed onto a nav controller that hopefully can help. This shouldn't have the problem that you described:

https://gist.github.com/spastorelli-stripe/9ec230dad7a7da5a6f85147deb6a4b3b

Comment: that did it for me, thanks! :)